# How to display the last element of a list in xml?

Tags: html, xml, list, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<decisions type="Decision[]">
    <item>
      <fees type="Fees[]">
        <item>
          <feeType type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[Tax1]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[15]]></value>
          </feeType>
          <percent type="String"></percent>
          <amount type="String"><![CDATA[25]]></amount>
          <currency type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></value>
          </currency>
          <minAmount type="String"></minAmount>
          <maxAmount type="String"></maxAmount>
          <suggestedAmount type="String"><![CDATA[30]]></suggestedAmount>
          <comment type="String"></comment>
        </item>
        <item>
          <feeType type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[Tax2]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[16]]></value>
          </feeType>
          <percent type="String"><![CDATA[1]]></percent>
          <amount type="String"></amount>
          <currency type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></value>
          </currency>
          <minAmount type="String"></minAmount>
          <maxAmount type="String"><![CDATA[500]]></maxAmount>
          <suggestedAmount type="String"><![CDATA[2]]></suggestedAmount>
          <comment type="String"></comment>
        </item>
        <item>
          <feeType type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[Tax3]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[18]]></value>
          </feeType>
          <percent type="String"><![CDATA[1]]></percent>
          <amount type="String"></amount>
          <currency type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></value>
          </currency>
          <minAmount type="String"></minAmount>
          <maxAmount type="String"></maxAmount>
          <suggestedAmount type="String"><![CDATA[2]]></suggestedAmount>
          <comment type="String"></comment>
        </item>
      </fees>
    </item>
    
    <item>
      <fees type="Fees[]">
        <item>
          <feeType type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[Tax1]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[15]]></value>
          </feeType>
          <percent type="String"></percent>
          <amount type="String"><![CDATA[30]]></amount>
          <currency type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></value>
          </currency>
          <minAmount type="String"></minAmount>
          <maxAmount type="String"></maxAmount>
          <suggestedAmount type="String"><![CDATA[32]]></suggestedAmount>
          <comment type="String"></comment>
        </item>
        <item>
          <feeType type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[Tax2]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[17]]></value>
          </feeType>
          <percent type="String"><![CDATA[1]]></percent>
          <amount type="String"></amount>
          <currency type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></value>
          </currency>
          <minAmount type="String"></minAmount>
          <maxAmount type="String"><![CDATA[500]]></maxAmount>
          <suggestedAmount type="String"><![CDATA[2.20]]></suggestedAmount>
          <comment type="String"></comment>
        </item>
        <item>
          <feeType type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[Tax3]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[18]]></value>
          </feeType>
          <percent type="String"><![CDATA[2]]></percent>
          <amount type="String"></amount>
          <currency type="NameValuePair">
            <name type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></name>
            <value type="String"><![CDATA[EUR]]></value>
          </currency>
          <minAmount type="String"></minAmount>
          <maxAmount type="String"></maxAmount>
          <suggestedAmount type="String"><![CDATA[2.20]]></suggestedAmount>
          <comment type="String"></comment>
        </item>
      </fees>
    </item>
  </decisions>
```

In this case there are 2 items in the decisions. There can be only one item inside, also more than two. In the document I am preparing, I must always show the last one, because it is the current one. I am currently using the following code, which I need to rework:

```
    <xsl:template match="decisions/item/fees/item">
      <xsl:if test="feeType/name != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="feeType/name"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="suggestedAmount &gt; 0">
              <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="suggestedAmount"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:if test="amount &gt; 0">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="amount"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="currency/name"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="percent &gt; 0">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="percent"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>%
              </xsl:if> 
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:if>           
   </xsl:template>
```

How to rework the example so that I can show only the last item of the xml ?
Will it be necessary to put an id in the decisions/item to sort it in some way
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you match on the last element with e.g. `match="decisions/item/fees/item[last()]"` then your template  only applies to any last `item` child (of all `item` children) of any `fees` parent element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case, however, I get the last suggestedAmount in both items - 2 and 2.2
I need to get from the second item the proposed Amounts, which are 32, 2.2 and 2.2

Comment: @Bellerephon, that sounds as if you want to use the `last()` predicate on `decisions/item[last()]/fees/item` instead but I have not fully understood your XML vocabulary.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong expression.
It happened the way you wrote it, for which I am grateful!
Nice and succesful day !